# Is it bad practice to add a class to a third party dependency/package? (java)

Tags: java, oop, android-gradle-plugin

I have an interaction client from a 3rd party dependency for a service I need to use. Some of the behaviors don't fit my use case and I want to try to extend or just rewrite an adapter for it, but a lot of the methods or variables I need are protected. Should I just write a class that belongs in that package to access those? I haven't ever heard it explicitly stated *not* to, but it seems to defeat the purpose of having a package in the first place.

Comment: You can just extend the required class and you will have access to the protected member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it's a very bad idea.  You should never, ever modify a 3rd party JAR in any way.  You're better off to consider them sealed.

The reason is two-fold:

1. You may break the dependency code.
2. The moment you modify that 3rd party JAR you have to modify every update in the same way.

You are free to extend a third party class, as long as it's not marked as `final`.  But it'll be part of *your* code if you do that.  You are free to pull in a new version of that 3rd party JAR any time it's available.

Answer (score 0):

If the methods and variables are protected, you can extend the class with your own implementation. The child class is able to access the parent class's protected variables and properties.

Your implementation does not need to be in the same package.